# No se guardan correctamente datos en objeto de clase en PHP POO

Tags: php, poo

Espero me puedan ayudar o darme una critica constructiva, u orientarme tengo un problema al asignar atributos a un objeto de clase, en las siguientes imagenes. Muestro un poco.

Esta es mi clase Automovil, con los metodos set y get

[image: Esta es la clase con metodos; set y get]

Ahora lo siguiente que hago es mandarla llamar para pasarle 
   valores a los atributos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al momento de verificar mediante el var dump, solo me esta guardando en 
   dicho objeto, valores para el atributo tipo
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Al momento de verificar si estoy enviando los valores del post, si estan 
los valores que quiero guardar.
```

[image: verificacion]
   [image: verifica en codigo]

Este es el metodo registrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como consecuencia en la base de datos, solo me guarda el valor asignado 
   al atributo tipo de la clase Automovil.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La persona, que quiero comentar una solución  y necesite más detalles
   hagamelo saber y con gusto se los doy.

Si tambien me pueden recomendar una referencia en internet, para solventar
   estos detalles.

Todo este codigo, es con el fin de realizar un abc en php, integrando 
   programación orientada a objetos.

:), es todo Gracias! ...

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a la comunidad, como observación, cualquier trozo de código que llegues a anexar en tu pregunta es preferible que lo hagas con texto y no en capturas/imagen, esto para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tengas el apoyo que deseas.

Comment: tomare en cuenta dicha observación, muchas gracias ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow.

Por lo general las clases tienen un *setter*  y un *getter* por cada atributo o propiedad de las mismas.

Esto quiere decir que, en este caso, la clase `Automovil` debería tener un *setter*  para las propiedades `$idautomovil, $marca, $modelo, $anio` ... y también un *getter*.

El *setter*  serviría para cambiar una propiedad determinada una vez que el objeto ha sido creado. Cuando al atributo de una clase es `private` no lo puedes modificar desde fuera de la clase mediante la asignación `$instancia->atributo="valor"`, como de hecho intentas hacer. Esto violaría uno de los principios fundamentales de la POO, que se conoce por *encapsulación*.

El *getter*  serviría para obtener esa propiedad.

Otro aspecto es el *constructor*  de la clase. Dentro de él puedes decidir dos cosas:

- Si la clase se creará siempre vacía de propiedades las cuales se setearan a posteriori (usando el *setter*). En ese caso la clase tendrá un constructor vacío:

  ```
   function __construct() {

   }
  ```

  Y la creación de instancia de la clase se escribiría así:

  ```
   $myAuto=new Automovil();
  ```
- O si se creará con todas o con algunas de sus propiedades. En ese caso el constructor deberá recibir en parámetro los valores de las propiedades y establecerlos con `$this`:

  ```
   function __construct($idautomovil, $marca, modelo,$anio,$tipo) {
       $this->idautomovil =$idautomovil;
       $this->marca=$marca;
       $this->modelo =$modelo;
       $this->anio=$anio;
       $this->tipo=$tipo;
   }
  ```

  Y la creación de instancia de la clase se escribiría así:

  ```
   $myAuto=new Automovil($idAutomovil,$marca,$modelo,$anio,$tipo);
  ```

Un ejemplo de tu clase podría ser este, entendiendo lo explicado más arriba:

```
class Automovil {

    private $id;
    private $marca;
    private $modelo;
    private $anio;
    private $tipo;

   function __construct() {
   }

    public function setMarca ($marca) {
        $this->marca=$marca;
    }

   public function getMarca () {
        return $this->marca;
    }

}
```

Probamos a crear una instancia:

```
$myAuto=new Automovil();
/*Seteamos la marca*/
$myAuto->setMarca("Nissan");
var_dump($myAuto);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(Automovil)#1 (5) {
  ["id":"Automovil":private]=>
  NULL
  ["marca":"Automovil":private]=>
  string(6) "Nissan"
  ["modelo":"Automovil":private]=>
  NULL
  ["anio":"Automovil":private]=>
  NULL
  ["tipo":"Automovil":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

Como podrás ver, el objeto tiene su marca.

He puesto sólo un getter y setter por motivos de brevedad, debes completar la clase con los demás getter y setter por cada propiedad de la misma.

---

### Uso de los métodos mágicos `__set` y `__get`

Si quieres usar los métodos mágicos, por lo mismo que hemos dicho más arriba, es preciso saber que el métdoo `__set`  sería para asignar la propiedad (no para retornar nada), esa función correspondería al método `__get`.

Dichos métodos se escribirían entonces así:

```
public function __set($k, $v) {
    $this->$k = $v;
}

public function __get($k) {
   return $this->$k;
}
```

El problema es que en tu método `__set` no estabas asignando el valor a la propiedad de la clase.

### ¿Es una buena práctica lo que estás haciendo?

En definitiva es una pésima práctica. Dejar un método `__set` abierto violaría con una facilidad pasmosa uno de los principios básicos de la POO: la encapsulación.

Eso quiere decir que alguien podría asignar una propiedad extraña al objeto `Automovil`, por ejemplo:

```
$myAuto->fakeProperty='Esta propiedad no existía y se creará arbitrariamente';
```

si revisas el objeto con `var_dump` podrás ver que en efecto, esa propiedad se ha creado en tu objeto:

```
  ...

  ["fakeProperty"]=>
  string(55) "Esta propiedad no existía y se creará arbitrariamente"

  ...
```

Lo que equivale a decir que no está encapsulado.

En realidad, **la verdadera utilidad de `__set` es precisamente **defender la encapsulación  del objeto**, lanzando una excepción y obligando a pasar por lo *setter*  legítimos para modificar el objeto:

```
public function __set($k, $v) {
   throw new Exception ('No se puede violar la encapsulación');
}
```

Haciendo esto, cuando se intente modificar el objeto añadiendo una `fakeProperty`, se levantará una excepción:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: No se puede violar la encapsulación in source_file.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 source_file.php(35): Automovil->__set('fakeProperty', 'Esta propiedad ...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in source_file.php on line 25
```

Para más detalles, recomendaría que leas las [notas contributivas de usuarios](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) en el Manual de PHP.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, tomare nota de su respuesta.

Comment: @FranciscoMS380 si quieres usar un sólo método entonces tu método mágico debe escribirse así: `public function __set($k, $v) {
        $this->$k = $v;
    }`  ... el problema es que no haces una asignación. Los *setter*, por lo dicho en la respuesta, no devuelven nada, sólo asignan valores.

Comment: No manches, entonces el error que tenia, en si es  que para set  y get se declara  asi : "$this->$k" y yo lo asignaba asi, de esta manera mira : "$this->k", pero es que asi es como regularmente se pone el this en como atributo de clase.                      Y fui a mi codigo e hice el cambio (  $this->k por  $this->$k  ) y ya lo pude corregir, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Que diferencia tan fustrante  ( $this->k por $this->$k).

Comment: @FranciscoMS380 si lo piensas bien, `k` no es un atributo de la clase, por lo tanto no funcionará como esperas. Es más, prueba esto: `public function __set($k, $v) {
         $this->k = $v;
    }` luego setea algo así por ejemplo: `$myAuto->tipo="4x4";` y haz un `var_dump` del objeto. Verás que ocurre lo que digo al final de la respuesta: una violación de la *encapsulación*, porque se crea una propiedad `k` para el objeto. No es aconsejable que dejes el método `__set` como lo tienes ahora, porque el objeto podría ser alterado sin ninguna restricción.

Comment: el resultado, si es verdad se crea otra propiedad:

Comment: object(Automovil)#2 (6) { ["idautomovil":"Automovil":private]=> NULL ["marca":"Automovil":private]=> NULL ["modelo":"Automovil":private]=> NULL ["anio":"Automovil":private]=> NULL ["tipo":"Automovil":private]=> NULL ["k"]=> string(5) "4 x 4" }

Comment: Gracias, todos los dias.. se aprende algo nuevo

Comment: @FranciscoMS380 creo que la mejor solución es escribir los *setter*  de forma explícita, y usar el método mágico para asegurar la *encapsulación*, blindando el objeto.Si la respuesta te ha ayudado a resolver el problema, por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: public function __GET($k){ return $this->$k; }

   //permiten acceder a los metodos privados
   public function __SET($k, $v){ 
      throw new Exception('No se puede violar la encapsulacion');
   } 

   public function setMarca($valor){ 
           $this->marca=$valor;
   }

Comment: Bueno al final asi quedo, Gracias ya salio ...

Comment: @FranciscoMS380 pero recuerda que **debe hacer un *setter* por cada miembro de la clase**, o sea: `setId(), setModelo(), setAnio(), setTipo()`... yo puse uno solo por razones de brevedad.

Comment: Si de hecho, asi lo tengo y tambien solo puse el setMarca, para ser breve, ahora bien el metodo __GET($k){ return $this->$k; }  tambien llevaria este mensaje throw new Exception('No se puede violar la encapsulacion'); y tambien se establecerian getter por cada atributo.

Comment: @FranciscoMS380 los *getter* no modifican para nada el objeto, es como si fueran de *sólo lectura*, sirven para obtener información sobre el objeto, por lo que puedes dejar (a mi entender)  el método mágico `__get` sin problema. El problema de cara a la encapsulación es `__set`, por el hecho de que permitiría modificar el objeto agregándole propiedades que no tiene.

Comment: Perfecto, muchisimas gracias....